# Custom Translator Pricing

Tags: price, microsoft-translator

The Translator Text API cost description is not clear to me on the page [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/customization/):

*Training a custom system is 1 character per character of training material in source text.*

- Is that a typo? 1 character per character of training material does not make sense to me. How should it be calculated if I opt for the  price tier S1 (pay as you go)?

*Hosting a deployed system is 1M characters per month per deployed system.*

- Does that mean if I am in the S1 tier, the monthly cost for hosting 4 deployed systems for the first 1M characters is $10x4=$40?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Training is charged per character in your source training material, with a minimum charge of 250K characters per training. For instance, if you had 500K characters in the source training material, you would be charged for 500K characters at the price for your tier. At the S1 level, that would be $5. The minimum charge for training is 250K characters ($2.50 at S1) if the source material has fewer than 250K characters.

Deployment is a flat charge of 1M characters per deployed system per month regardless of the number of characters in the training material. Yes, if you had 4 deployed systems at the S1 level, it would be $10 per system, so $10x4=$40 total per month for the 4 systems.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, a) training fee will be a one-off charge every time we train a system; b) hosting/deployment fee is charged based on the volume of the system at the rate of 1M per char; c) and on top of that, we will be paying $10 per million per character using the system to translate at price tier S1. Could you please confirm? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry our response was confusing: a) Yes, there is a charge every time you train a system. b) Hosting/deploying a model is not based on the volume of the system. There is only a 1M character per month flat fee per deployed system. c) The price to use the deployed customized system is the same as using the regular un-customized Translator service.

We hope this clarifies the pricing model.

Comment: Hello, regarding (b), what does that 1M characters refer to? The number of characters that are used in translation?

Comment: Hi Simon. 1M refers to 1 million characters. Microsoft Translator counts in characters and you are billed based on your Translator Text API subscription tier that is tied to your Custom Translator workspace.

Comment: Thanks, it clear to me now. Btw, I am wondering if I subscribe the S2 level, will the subscription fee also cover the training cost? That is, if the training fee is $500, can it be deducted from the $2k subscription fee and as a result we will have fewer characters to use for the API?

Comment: Yes, the costs of training and hosting are charged as usage to your subscription in characters, and it does reduce the amount of available characters left for use of the API. Overage is available at the S2-4 levels at a reduced rate from the S1 level.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying pricing.  Has a decision been made on the pricing for General Availability, or is the pricing above only for preview period?